# Google BigQuery SQL: how to convert procedure to function that returns table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wrote a procedure that works well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE project.dataset.test_procedure 
    (v_month int64, v_year int64)
BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Date,
            User_ID,
            Amount
        FROM 
            test_table
    )
    SELECT 
        User_ID,
        SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
    FROM 
        CTE 
    WHERE 
        extract(month from Date) = v_month 
        AND extract(year from Date) = v_year;
END;
```

I need to create a **function** that returns a table by two variables (include CTE statement):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.dataset.test_function (v_month int64 , v_year int64 ) 
Returns  table
(
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Date,
       User_ID,
       Amount
FROM test_table
)
SELECT User_ID,
       sum(Amount) AS Total_Amount
FROM CTE 
WHERE extract(month from Date)=v_month and extract(year from Date)=v_year;
END;
)
```

I have seen some examples, but I can not figure out how to write a function correctly that returns a table...

How to do it right in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below toy example of exact what you are looking for

```
create temp table test_table as
  select 1 User_ID, 10 Amount, date '2021-01-01' Date union all 
  select 1, 20, '2021-01-01' union all 
  select 1, 30, '2021-02-01' union all 
  select 2, 40, '2021-01-01' 
;

create temp function test_function (v_month int64 , v_year int64 ) as (
array(
  select as struct
    Date,
    User_ID,
    Amount
  from test_table
  where extract(month from Date) = v_month 
  and extract(year from Date)=v_year
));
select User_ID,
  sum(Amount) AS Total_Amount
from unnest(test_function(1, 2021)) 
group by User_ID
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It is possible to create a standard (not temp ) function like in standard MS SQL and call it by two variables?

Comment: I used temp USF just so you can test and play with it. You can replace temp USF with permanent and it still will work!

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TABLE FUNCTION `project.dataset.test_procedure`
(v_month int64, v_year int64)
AS (
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT Date,User_ID,Amount
        FROM `project.dataset.test_table`
    )
    SELECT User_ID, SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE extract(month from Date) = v_month 
      AND extract(year from Date) = v_year
    GROUP BY User_ID
);
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Standard function is more complicated, but work too

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION `project.dataset.test_procedure` (v_month int64, v_year int64)
AS (
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- declare v_month int64;
    -- declare v_year  int64;
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- select * 
    -- from unnest(`project.dataset.test_procedure`(v_month, v_year))
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ARRAY (
            WITH CTE AS
            (
                SELECT Date,User_ID,Amount
                FROM `project.dataset.test_table`
            )
            SELECT AS STRUCT User_ID, SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
            FROM CTE
            WHERE extract(month from Date) = v_month
              AND extract(year  from Date) = v_year
            GROUP BY User_ID
          )
  );
```